# Print grand total at last page with other detail

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to print a grand total on the last page of my report. But i don't want that grand total to print on its own page without any other detail data.

I put my grand total in the report footer and set it to print on the final page. But in some cases, the last page is empty apart from that footer- when the data displayed on the second-to-last page completely fills the page.

I tried to put the grand total in page footer and suppress it when `currentPage < totalPage`, but it leaves useless blank spaces. How can I achieve the correct functionality?

Answer (score 0):

If the `currentPage < totalPage` solution works for you, apart from the blank space it leaves behind, there is hope. Try reimplementing that fix and activate *Suppress Blank Section* for that Footer.

There's also a clever little hack you can do where you vertically shrink the Footer section and Grand Total field until they both have barely any height to them. Then mark the Total both as *Can Grow.* When suppressed, the footer and total be as small as they are on the Design view. But when they're not suppressed, they both grow to fit the text.

---

As requested, to limit the Details section to printing a maximum of 14 per page, you'll want to put this formula in its *New Page After* section:

```
RecordNumber MOD 14 = 0
```

Comment: hi 4444, thanks for taking time to reply my question and also edit the wrong grammar. i have tried to suppress (currentPage < totalPage) and suppress when blank but still won't work.. Can i set the detail section to print for n lines ? The line count not the line of the detail item. So what i want to achieve is to print the detail section for maximum 14 lines, the rest 5 lines is for the grand total section.. regards..

Comment: @cumibulat I've updated my answer to include a way to limit the records per page

Comment: hi, in this New Page After there are 2 options. a)End of Section B) n Visible records. Your formula is work same like option B. And i apology maybe my previous comment didn't give you a right picture. I want to get the line number not the Record Number, where Record Number maybe consist of two or more line if it sets to can grow.

Comment: @cumibulat No, you wouldn't be able to get the number of lines. I recommend doing the second paragraph instead.